# How Do I Connect an MVC Razor Pages Project to an MS Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, entity-framework-6, razor-pages

I created a Razor Pages Project in Visual Studio 2017. 
I have an existing MS Access database with several tables.
(Courses and Sponsors).
I want to use Entity Framework to have Scaffolding create the basic CRUD pages.

I am totally lost, and I have searched for anything that will help.
I imported 2 packages using NuGet
System.Data.Odbc
MSA.NetCore.ODBC
but I have no idea how to configure a connection string and DbContext class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, pretty sure Access driver is a choice when creating a Connection.
Pick ODBC datasources> MS Access.

What threw me off was my dev computer only recognizes the old ".mdb" MS Access format.
I was looking for an MS Access driver for the ".accdb" format (newer). This is a known fault on my dev box. The correct dlls are not installed. Proof of this is I can import ".xls" files into my SSMS 2017, but not ".xlsx". This is another story for another bedtime.

My workaround was to port the MS Access tables to SQLIte, download an SQLite ODBC driver, and an SQLite browser and make a connect, using the ODBC option from VS 2017 to my project. whew.